# Other methods for solving homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find a general solution of the following homogeneous equation

> $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{3t+12y}{t+14y}$$

I have tried using the substitution $z = y/t$ to make the equation separable, but then it gets a little bit tedious to solve.

> $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{3+12z}{1+14z}=z+\frac{dz}{dt}t$$
>
> $$\int \frac{1+14z}{-14z^2+11z+3} dz = \ln(t)+c_1$$

**So I'm wondering if there's another way to solve it?**

Comment: What about $y = tx$?

Comment: @openspace what about it? I have y=zt

Comment: I've edited your question a bunch to make the intention more clear.

Comment: @Dylan thanks mate

Comment: And to answer your actual question: The homogeneous substitution you've already done is (I think) the most "convenient" method you can use. It's a good thing that the tedious integration is the easy part.

Comment: The substitution is actually the best thing perhaps. I cannot think of an easier method to evaluate this. Sure it might be long and tedious but it will definitely not be too hard.

Comment: alright, I can put up with it then

Answer (score 2):

My teacher in ODEs show me this "rarely unknown"substitution method, it Works with homogeneous and almost homogeneous ODEs.

1° Let $y=p^S$ and $t=q^R$, respectively  $dy=Sp^{S-1}dS$, $dt=Rq^{R-1}dR$; R and S are constants. Then substitute in the ODE:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3t+12y}{t+14y}\rightarrow\frac{Sp^{S-1}dS}{Rq^{R-1}dR}=\frac{3q^R+12p^S}{q^R+14p^S}$$
$$\frac{S\ dS}{R\ dR}=\frac{q^{R-1}(3q^R+12p^S)}{p^{S-1}(q^R+14p^S)}$$
$$\frac{S\ dS}{R\ dR}=\frac{3q^{2R-1}+12p^Sq^{R-1}}{p^{S-1}q^R+14p^{2S-1}}$$
Match the all the upper exponents with all the lowers

$$2R-1+S+R-1+=S-1+R+2S-1\\3R+S=3S+R\\R=S$$

The only restriction is $(R,S)>0\quad$  I'll do it easier with $R=1$ we obtain:
$$\frac{dS}{dR}=\frac{3q+12p}{q+14p}$$ we got the same initial ODE, so we're right.

$\star\quad $ 2° Method we want $F(\lambda^\alpha t,\lambda^\beta y)=\lambda^{\beta-\alpha}F(t,y)\ $ to be homogeneous, and the substitution must be $y=\sigma t^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}$
$$\frac{3\lambda t+12\lambda y}{\lambda t+14\lambda y}\\\lambda^0\left(\frac{3t+12y}{t+14y}\right)$$ it works with bigger exponents but in this case $\alpha=\beta=1$ then $y=\sigma t$ the easiest substitution .

$\star\quad $ 3° Another method could be; from $dy/dt=3(t-4y)/(t+14y)\ $Let $u=t+4y\ $ then $du=dt+4dy$
$$\frac{\frac14(du-dt)}{dt}=\frac{3u}{t+\frac72(u-t)}\\\frac14\frac{du}{dt}-\frac14=\frac{6u}{7u-5t}\\\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{31u-5t}{7u-5t}$$ but its unnecessary cause its the same traditional method, in another form.Also you can do it letting $\omega=t+14y$

All these methods are long and again unnecessary, your integral is easier enough, the first method its for different exponents for a  ODE like this: $y'=(x^2y+yx^3)/(y+y^2x)$